# How to remove file from git history without diverging the history?

Tags: git, github

Let's say developer A (original author) creates a repository. He makes an initial commit in which he includes big binary file.
Developer B (me) creates a fork and commits removal of that binary (it still stays in history). After that B makes more changes to the fork, while A's repo remains untouched.
How can B remove the file from history without creating completely diverging histories with A's repo (I'm ok with several diverging commits)? Or at least disable automatic cloning of that binary when cloning the repo.

I've tried `git filter-branch`, `git-filter-repo` and `git rebase -i`. They all create diverging histories.

Comment: with https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/ I used it several times, it works great

Comment: @Mate: That will create diverging histories which OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: You don't. It's not possible. Either history is shared or it is not. You can't have different histories with the same hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply not possible, due to the design and operating principles of Git.  Two repos with different things in their history are not going to converge to the same set of commit hashes later on.